# Problemas em formatação html

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados, imagem, formatação

Eu tenho um upload de imagens com texto num site e após inserir mostra as imagens e texto. O upload grava as imagens numa pasta e o seu **path** na base de dados.
É suposto ficar assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

umas por baixo das outra, assim organizadas. Mas quando se insere outra, isto acontece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ficam umas em cima das outra! Se ajudar eu deixo aqui o código:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:25px">


      <?php 
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","neo");
        mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf-8");

        $result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from know_how");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $txt = $row['texto'];
            $img = $row['ficheiro'];
            echo "<div class='col-md-6' style='padding: 10px;width:450px;height:355px'>
            <img data-toggle='modal' src='$img'class='img-responsive img-thumbnail' width='100%;' style='height:350px;'>
            <a href='apagarO.php?id=$id'><img src='../images/delete.png' width='20px' style='margin-left: 415px; '></a>
            </div>

            <div style='padding-top: 25px;'><p style='text-align:center;'>$txt</p></div>";
        }
      ?>
```

Ai está a  toda. Alguém me pode ajudar? Preciso mesmo disso.

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque no seu CSS a propriedade

```
display : block;
```

ou direto na sua tag html

```
<div style="display:block"/>
//sua imagem

</div>
```

Ela fará com que você consiga o resultado desejado

Comment: Pois já experimentei fazer isso antes mas fica na mesma

Comment: no caso, seria colocar esse atributo na div pai da tag html, já tentou também?

Comment: eu criei uma <div> e coloquei <div style="display:block"> Código </div>. O código em cima todo dentro dessa <div>

Comment: não existe razão para o block não estar funcionando, adicione uma classe na div externa e crie uma regra no css para essa classe, Agrupe todas as tags de uma imagem em uma <div class="row"> do bootstrap, abraço

Comment: Tem toda a razão foi uma tag que eu não fechei que estava a fazer isso. Obrigado!

Comment: De nada, acontece! (: